# Elm read HTTP response body for non-200 response

Tags: elm

How to read HTTP response body for a non 200 HTTP status

```
getJson : String -> String -> Effects Action
getJson url credentials =
  Http.send Http.defaultSettings
    { verb = "GET"
    , headers = [("Authorization", "Basic " ++ credentials)]
    , url = url
    , body = Http.empty
    }
    |> Http.fromJson decodeAccessToken
    |> Task.toResult
    |> Task.map UpdateAccessTokenFromServer
    |> Effects.task
```

The above promotes the error from

```
Task.toResult : Task Http.Error a -> Task x (Result Http.Error a)
```

The value of which becomes

(BadResponse 400 ("Bad Request"))

My server responds with what is wrong with the request as a JSON payload in the response body. Please help me retrieve that from the Task x a into ServerResult below.

```
type alias ServerResult = { status : Int, message : String }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Http package (v3.0.0)](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-http/3.0.0/Http) does not expose an easy way to treat HTTP codes outside of the 200 to 300 range as non-error responses. Looking at the source code, [the `handleResponse` function is looking between the hardcoded 200 to 300 range](https://github.com/evancz/elm-http/blob/3.0.0/src/Http.elm#L434)

However, with a bit of copy and pasting from that Http package source code, you can create a custom function to replace `Http.fromJson` in order to handle HTTP status codes outside the normal "success" range.

Here's an example of the bare minimum you'll need to copy and paste to create a custom `myFromJson` function that acts the same as the Http package except for the fact it also treats a 400 as a success:

```elm
myFromJson : Json.Decoder a -> Task Http.RawError Http.Response -> Task Http.Error a
myFromJson decoder response =
  let decode str =
        case Json.decodeString decoder str of
          Ok v -> Task.succeed v
          Err msg -> Task.fail (Http.UnexpectedPayload msg)
  in
      Task.mapError promoteError response
        `Task.andThen` myHandleResponse decode


myHandleResponse : (String -> Task Http.Error a) -> Http.Response -> Task Http.Error a
myHandleResponse handle response =
  if (200 <= response.status && response.status < 300) || response.status == 400 then

      case response.value of
        Http.Text str ->
            handle str

        _ ->
            Task.fail (Http.UnexpectedPayload "Response body is a blob, expecting a string.")

  else

      Task.fail (Http.BadResponse response.status response.statusText)

-- copied verbatim from Http package because it was not exposed
promoteError : Http.RawError -> Http.Error
promoteError rawError =
  case rawError of
    Http.RawTimeout -> Http.Timeout
    Http.RawNetworkError -> Http.NetworkError
```

Again, that code snippet is almost entirely copy and pasted except for that 400 status check. Copying and pasting like that is usually a last resort, but because of the library restrictions, it seems to be one of your only options at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. :) I'll try this.
I've also created an issue to see if this can be fixed at the library level.